# Netbeans 8 fast insert tag BR

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

Usually in other HTML editors shortcut CTRL ENTER is insert 
 tag.
I don't understand how to assign in the Netbeans 8 that shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans supports editor macros.

- Open a document.
- Click in it to set an initial cursor position.
- Click "`Edit > Start Macro Recording`".
- Type "`<br>`" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Click "`Edit > Stop Macro Recording`".
- You will now be prompted to name your macro. Use something obvious like `br insert`.
- Click `OK`
- Click `Set Shortcut...` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to assign a shortcut to the macro.

Comment: this is not very good, more clever editors look at the file extension and insert either \n or <br /> depending on the filetype